# BeautifulSoup missing/skipping tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction. Is there a better way of doing this and capture all the data (with html tags class "Document Text")) ...

If i do like this. I missing some tags in the end orginal html string is 20K in size(so its lot of data).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
c.case_html = str(soup.find('div', class_='DocumentText')
print(self.case_html)
```

Following is the code for scraping which works fine for now but the second new tag is added it is broken.

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
 c.case_html = str(soup.find('div', class_='DocumentText').find_all(['p','center','small']))
 print(self.case_html)
```

Sample html is as follows original is around the 20K string size

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<div id="theDocument" class="DocumentText" style="position: relative; float: left; overflow: scroll; height: 739px;">
<p>PTag</p>
<p> <center> First center </center> </p>
<small> this is small</small>
<p>...</p>
<p> <center> Second Center </center> </p>
<p>....</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Expected output to be this

```
<div id="theDocument" class="DocumentText" style="position: relative; float: left; overflow: scroll; height: 739px;">
<p>PTag</p>
<p> <center> First center </center> </p>
<small> this is small</small>
<p>...</p>
<p> <center> Second Center </center> </p>
<p>....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `c.case_html = str(soup.find('div', class_='DocumentText')` why are you converting this to `string` ?

Comment: What text you wanna parse from the elements pasted above?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected out put to be everything between the <div> </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I just based my answer on your given html code. If you need clarifications, just let me know. Thanks!

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
 case_html = soup.select('div.DocumentText')
 print(case_html.get_text())
```